# Object required - Passing variable to Function

Tags: excel, parameter-passing, vba

I'm taking first stab at Excel VBA having learned some VBA from an Access project. I am trying to find the first and second visible cells on a dataset that is filtered. My current method is to find the first visible cell  via a sub function, and then use that first cell reference to find the next one. I get the Object required error when I compile on `Vis1cell =`

Here's the code:

```
Sub volvar()
'
' Volume Var Sort Macro
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim filterDept As Range

Dim volrng As String
Dim Vis1 As Range
Dim Vis1cell As String
Dim Vis2 As Range
Dim Vis2cell As String

Set rng = Range("$A$12:$BF$45000")
Set filterDept = Range("D8")

'volrng is static and just needs to be passed to the function.
volrng = "J12"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
    Set Vis1cell = VolVis(volrng)
    Set Vis1 = Range(Vis1cell)
    Set Vis2cell = VolVis(Vis1cell)
    Set Vis2 = Range(Vis2cell)

    Debug.Print "Vis1"; Vis1
    Debug.Print "Vis2"; Vis2
End With

    'if FilterCheck = 1, sort based on dept and then order
    If FilterCheck = 1 Then
        If Vis1 > Vis2 Then
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 1 Asc"
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterDept.Value
            End With
            GoTo FilterAsc
        Else
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 1 Desc"
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterDept.Value
            End With
            GoTo FilterDesc
        End If
    Else
        If Range("J13") > Range("J14") Then
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 0 Asc"
            GoTo FilterAsc
        Else
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 0 Desc"
            GoTo FilterDesc
        End If
    End If

FilterAsc:
    Debug.Print "Asc Goto"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=10
        rng.CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("J12"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    Exit Sub

FilterDesc:
    Debug.Print "Desc Goto"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=10
        rng.CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("J12"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
            Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

And here is the function I'm trying to pass to:

```
Function VolVis(rng As String) As String

    ActiveSheet.Range(rng).Select
    'Set rng = Range("J12")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    Set VolVis = ActiveCell.Address

    Debug.Print "Cell Address"; VolVis

End Function
```

Comment: One thing that looks funny to me is in your `VolVis` function you are using `Set VolVis = ActiveCell.Address` when I think it should just be `VolVis = ActiveCell.Address`

Comment: Also I just noticed you are trying to use `Set` when assigning a string to a variable.  This isn't proper syntax.  Instead of `Set Vis1cell = VolVis(volrng)` try `Vis1cell = VolVis(volrng)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is using the keyword `Set`.  `Set` is used for setting an object reference, instead of simply assigning a value.

You correctly assign a string here:

`volrng = "J12"`

`Vis1cell` is declared as a string, but you are trying to reference an object.

The line:

`Set Vis1cell = VolVis(volrng)`

Should simply be:

`Vis1cell = VolVis(volrng)`

Now, a `Range` is an object that needs to be set.  So the line:

`Set Vis1 = Range(Vis1cell)`

is correct.

You also reference the `Range` object often and you look to be trying to compare two values.  To access the value of a range, you must use `Range.Value`.

For example, if you are trying to compare the two values in J13 and J14, this will not work:

`Range("J13") > Range("J14")`

You haven't specified **what** about the ranges you want to compare.  Since you are using the `>` operator, I'll assume the values.  To compare values, you must do something like:

`Range("J13").Value > Range("J14").Value`

I've made changes where appropriate in my code and added my initials in comment `'JR` to help you see how it should look.

```
Sub volvar()
'
' Volume Var Sort Macro
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim filterDept As Range

Dim volrng As String
Dim Vis1 As Range
Dim Vis1cell As String
Dim Vis2 As Range
Dim Vis2cell As String

Set rng = Range("$A$12:$BF$45000")
Set filterDept = Range("D8")

'volrng is static and just needs to be passed to the function.
volrng = "J12"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
    Vis1cell = VolVis(volrng) 'JR
    Set Vis1 = Range(Vis1cell)
    Vis2cell = VolVis(Vis1cell) 'JR
    Set Vis2 = Range(Vis2cell)

    Debug.Print "Vis1"; Vis1.Address 'JR
    Debug.Print "Vis2"; Vis2.Address 'JR
End With

    'if FilterCheck = 1, sort based on dept and then order
    If FilterCheck = 1 Then
        If Vis1.Value > Vis2.Value Then 'JR
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 1 Asc"
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterDept.Value
            End With
            GoTo FilterAsc
        Else
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 1 Desc"
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterDept.Value
            End With
            GoTo FilterDesc
        End If
    Else
        If Range("J13").Value > Range("J14").Value Then 'JR
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 0 Asc"
            GoTo FilterAsc
        Else
            Debug.Print "FilterCheck 0 Desc"
            GoTo FilterDesc
        End If
    End If

FilterAsc:
    Debug.Print "Asc Goto"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=10
        rng.CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("J12"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    Exit Sub

FilterDesc:
    Debug.Print "Desc Goto"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=10
        rng.CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("J12"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
            Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

And for your Function, you are returning a string, so the `Set` keyword is incorrect syntax.  It should look like:

```
Function VolVis(rng As String) As String

    ActiveSheet.Range(rng).Select
    'Set rng = Range("J12")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    VolVis = ActiveCell.Address

    Debug.Print "Cell Address"; VolVis

End Function
```

You can read more about the appropriate use of the Set keyword [here](http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_set_keyword.html).  Or you can follow a YouTube video tutorial on `Dim` vs `Set` and their appropriate uses [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S55cKcgF1jk).

Comment: thank you for the clarification on usage of Set. This makes sense with your explanations. Also, thank you for the detailed fixes for everything! Everything works now.